# Variable of indeterminate type

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains a variable of indeterminate type, which must be overridden at runtime, how can I do this?

Sorry for the disgusting question(
Example:

```
public class MyClass 
{
     public e_Type TypeValue;
     public (variable of indeterminate type) Value;
}


public enum e_Type
{
    string, int, bool, byte
}
```

At runtime variable TypeValue should determine the type of variable Value

Comment: var is known at compile time. Do you need "dynamic"?

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're *really* after generics:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; };
}
```

Then you can create instances for different types:

```
Foo<string> x = new Foo<string>();
x.Value = "fred";

Foo<int> y = new Foo<int>();
y.Value = 10;
```

This is still fixing the type at compile-time - but when the code *using* the type is compiled.

`var` is completely wrong here - `var` is just used for [implicitly typed local variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx). In particular, you can't apply it to fields.

It's *possible* that you want `dynamic`, but it's not really clear from your question at the moment.

Comment: How can I apply this to my example??

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you actually mean, you should use either `var` or `dynamic`.

The `var` keyword simply lets the compiler take care of deciding which type you are actually using. If the data you will be assigning is truly dynamic during runtime, **it won't do you much good**. You should mostly look at `var` as syntactic sugar (even if it at times can be very, very helpful sugar) - i.e. it just saves you typing.

The `dynamic` keyword lets you create an object that is truly dynamic, that is you will not get a compiler or runtime error no matter what you try to assign to it. The runtime errors will happen later down the road when you try to call on a property that doesn't exist on it. This is essentially you telling the compiler "*Hey, look, just don't give me any fuss about this object, allow me to assign anything to it and call anything on it. If I mess up, it's my problem, not yours.*"

I think whenever you are thinking about using `dynamic` you should consider the problem at hand and see if it can be solved in a better way (interfaces, generics etc).

Answer (score 2):

> I know that this must be done using the keyword var

Nope, that isn't what `var` does. There are 3 things that leap to mind that *would* work:

- `object`; can store anything, but requires reflection to do anything useful
- `dynamic`; a special-case of object, where the compiler performs voodoo such that `obj.SomeMethod()` (etc) is resolved at runtime
- generics, i.e. have the class be `SomeType<T>`, with the variable typed as `T`; generic constraints can make this `T` more usable by declaring features (interfaces) that it must have

Answer (score 0):

`var` has the purpose of *referencing* anything, not to *declare* anything. It's the other way around.

I acomplished this once leveraging the `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` (C# 4 only!), it allows for properties to be added at will without declaring them, and they will be resolved at runtime (it resembles how PHP treats objects and I'm a huge fan of it).

A quick example:

```
dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();
myObject.myProperty = "You can declare properties on-the-fly inside me !";
Console.WriteLine(myObject.myProperty);
```

Comment: Since he says the variable must be overridden at runtime, I think he already has some incoming object/data, i.e. declaring a new, explicit object probably isn't what he's after.

Comment: Well, I guess we'll never know.